# How to reduce heroku slug size

Tags: python, heroku

I am trying to deploy machine learning app on heroku
Its giving me the following error

```
remote:  !     Compiled slug size: 534M is too large (max is 500M).
```

Files:

```
app.py
chatbot.h5
classes.pkl
words.pkl
data.json
preprocessor.py
Procfile
requirements.txt
runtime.txt
wsgi.py
```

requirement.txt

```
Flask==2.0.3
Jinja2==3.0.3
keras==2.6.0
nltk==3.6.7
numpy==1.19.5
tensorflow==2.6.2
```

Answer (score 2):

It's numpy, have had that package screw things up before.  It's a monster.

Take a look here: https://help.heroku.com/KUFMEES1/my-slug-size-is-too-large-how-can-i-make-it-smaller

A long time ago our team had to install requirements (numpy and scipy) after we pushed the app.  Not really ideal in Heroku, but it may be possible.

Numpy can bulge to 700mb: https://numpy.org/install/ - I almost never use this package, but you may be able to mess with Basic Linear Algebra Subprograms included.